# Using sed to enable .htaccess files in Apache config

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, apache-http-server, sed

I am trying to automate the provisioning of an Ubuntu Vagrant box with a Bash script. All is well, but I am having difficulty with configuring Apache to allow overrides from `.htaccess` files. In my config file, there is the following block:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

All I need to do is replace `AllowOverride None` with `AllowOverride all`. This seems to be a task for `sed`, but there are other `<Directory>` blocks in this config file where I do not want to allow override.

How can I use sed to replace a specific string with a new string, when that specific string occurs between two other specific strings?

In other words, how can I replace `AllowOverride None` only when it appears between `<Directory /var/www/>` and `</Directory>`?

I can use the following command to get the block I am interested in:

```
sed -n '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/p' 000-default
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`sed` supports pattern ranges in this form:

```
sed '/startpattern/,/endpattern/ <sed-commands>' file
```

For example:

```
sed '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride all/' httpd.conf
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!